# Change box color for Cookie Script

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the "Got it!" box color in this cookie script.  I have changed all other colors.
I think the color is in the.js
Is there css code I can add to change that yellow box to another color?
By the way this is Blogger.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" id="cookieinfo"
src="//cookieinfoscript.com/js/cookieinfo.min.js"
data-bg="#645862"
data-fg="#FFFFFF"
data-link="#F1D600"
data-cookie="CookieInfoScript"
data-text-align="left"
   data-close-text="Got it!">
   </script>
```

Comment: "I want to change the "Got it!" box color" - Background colour of the infobox (We use cookies, etc), background colour of the 'Got it!' button, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `"#F1D600"` is the default color of `data-divlinkbg` (which it is background color of the button, according to the [documentation](https://cookieinfoscript.com/#customizing)), so if you want another color, for example `#ff0000`, you have to define it. Also, the `data-link` is the color of the button's text, which I defined as `#000000`. Altogether, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookieinfo"
src="//cookieinfoscript.com/js/cookieinfo.min.js"
data-bg="#645862"
data-fg="#FFFFFF"
data-link="#000000"
data-divlinkbg="#ff0000"
data-cookie="CookieInfoScript"
data-text-align="left"
   data-close-text="Got it!">
   </script>
```